# Unity Applying Global Light Settings fog to a non-main camera

Tags: unity, rendering, camera, lighting, fog

Is it possible to apply fog to a non-main camera?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Lighting Settings -> Fog ... works for the main camera but not the non-main camera... is there some sort of setting to be set?